# Counting number of graphs with a maximal connected component of size C on N nodes with N directed edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to come up with a (fast) way of calculating the number of graphs of N nodes and E edges that has a maximal connected component of size C.

For the purposes of connected components, consider the graph undirected, for the purposes of uniqueness of a graph consider the edges directed. Loops are not allowed. Vertices are labeled. Note the components do not necessarily need to be trees.

So, on 3 nodes there are 8 ways of having a 3 connected component.

[(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)]

[(a,b),(b,c),(c,b)]

[(a,b),(b,a),(c,a)]

[(a,b),(b,a),(c,b)]

[(a,c),(b,c),(c,a)]

[(a,c),(b,c),(c,b)]

[(a,c),(b,a),(c,a)]

[(a,c),(b,a),(c,b)]

There are $(N-1)^N$ possible graphs, so brute force is impossible.

Comment: Sadly, what you are trying to do is not going to be quick. If you fix $E = N-1$ and take $C = N$, and totally ignore edge orientation, then your problem becomes that of counting the number of unlabelled trees on $N$ vertices. This is a known hard problem; yours is at least as bad (probably worse). I would post this as an answer, except that I can't actually see how to prove that counting unlabelled trees with edge orientation isn't easier in some unexpected way.

Comment: The vertices are labeled, and the total graph doesn't need to be connected, so it's a fairly different problem. I will update the question though.

Comment: Did you mean that outdegree of each vertex is 1? Otherwise you example looks strange. (Anyway for 3 vertices there always only 1 component in base, so I assume 3 was a typo.)